# Add item to combobox after data source selected

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to add an item to the combobox after binding it. for example:

```
DataSet csuname = new DataSet();
csu.Fill(csuname);
comboBox1.DataSource = csuname.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "empfname";
comboBox1.Items.Add("all");
```

but it gets error like

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is
>   set.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Comment: That is an important piece of information. Please edit your post to include the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert item in combobox after binding it from a Dataset in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374880/insert-item-in-combobox-after-binding-it-from-a-dataset-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You cannot directly add object to combo after you set the datasource...so add a row to datatable and refresh the datasource..

Comment: Please look into the @Bob comment.. That is the proper answer for your question.

Comment: Look into this link also [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533875/items-collection-cannot-be-modified-when-the-datasource-property-is-set-c-sharp]

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add the item directly to your data source `csunam.Tables[0]` which I'd also assume needs to be an observable collection for this to work.